# Getting only a part of the page source using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the HTML of Billboard's top 100 chart, but I keep getting only about half of the page.

I tried getting the page source using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
s=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url = "https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/"
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print(driver.page_source)
```

But it always returns the page source only from the 53rd song on the chart (I've tried increasing the implicit wait and nothing changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are getting 53 elements. Using explicit waits I am getting all 100 elements.

User webdriverwait() as an explicit wait.

```
driver.get('https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100/')
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.lrv-a-unstyle-list h3#title-of-a-story")))
print(len(elements))
print([item.text for item in elements])
```

Need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

OutPut:

```
100
['Anti-Hero', 'Lavender Haze', 'Maroon', 'Snow On The Beach', 'Midnight Rain', 'Bejeweled', 'Question...?', "You're On Your Own, Kid", 'Karma', 'Vigilante Shit', 'Unholy', 'Bad Habit', 'Mastermind', 'Labyrinth', 'Sweet Nothing', 'As It Was', 'I Like You (A Happier Song)', "I Ain't Worried", 'You Proof', "Would've, Could've, Should've", 'Bigger Than The Whole Sky', 'Super Freaky Girl', 'Sunroof', "I'm Good (Blue)", 'Under The Influence', 'The Great War', 'Vegas', 'Something In The Orange', 'Wasted On You', 'Jimmy Cooks', 'Wait For U', 'Paris', 'High Infidelity', 'Tomorrow 2', 'Titi Me Pregunto', 'About Damn Time', 'The Kind Of Love We Make', 'Late Night Talking', 'Cuff It', 'She Had Me At Heads Carolina', 'Glitch', 'Me Porto Bonito', 'Die For You', 'California Breeze', 'Dear Reader', 'Forever', 'Hold Me Closer', 'Just Wanna Rock', '5 Foot 9', 'Unstoppable', 'Thank God', 'Fall In Love', 'Rock And A Hard Place', 'Golden Hour', 'Heyy', 'Half Of Me', 'Until I Found You', 'Victoria’s Secret', 'Son Of A Sinner', "Star Walkin' (League Of Legends Worlds Anthem)", 'Romantic Homicide', 'What My World Spins Around', 'Real Spill', "Don't Come Lookin'", 'Monotonia', 'Stand On It', 'Never Hating', 'Wishful Drinking', 'No Se Va', 'Free Mind', 'Not Finished', 'Music For A Sushi Restaurant', 'Pop Out', 'Staying Alive', 'Poland', 'Whiskey On You', 'Billie Eilish.', 'Betty (Get Money)', '2 Be Loved (Am I Ready)', 'Wait In The Truck', 'All Mine', 'La Bachata', 'Last Last', 'Glimpse Of Us', 'Freestyle', 'Calm Down', 'Gatubela', 'Evergreen', 'Pick Me Up', 'Gotta Move On', 'Perfect Timing', 'Country On', 'Snap', 'She Likes It', 'Made You Look', 'Dark Red', 'From Now On', 'Forget Me', 'Miss You', 'Despecha']
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.implicitly_wait(10)` is **not** a pause command!
It has no effect on the next line `print(driver.page_source)`.
If you want to wait for page to be completely load you can wait for some specific element there to be visible. Use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` for that. Or just add a hardcoded pause `time.sleep(10)` instead of `driver.implicitly_wait(10)`